# Strip array of url and other characters, show only post name

Tags: php, xml

The xml is like this: (wordpress url's) I want to strip them and get only the posts words.
http://www.site1.com/dir/this-is-page/
http://www.site2.com/this-is-page

**How do i strip the url's and get only "this is page" (without the rest of the urls, and the "-") if i have two diffrent types of urls; one with dir and one without dir? Sample code bellow:**

```
$feeds = array('http://www.site1.com/dir/feed.xml', 'http://www.site2.com/feed.xml');

foreach($feeds as $feed) 
{ 
  $xml = simplexml_load_file($feed);

  foreach( $xml->url as $url )
 {     
    $loc = $url->loc; 
 echo $loc;
 $locstrip = explode("/",$loc);
 $locstripped = $locstrip[4]; 
 echo '<br />';

 echo $locstripped;

 echo '<br />';

 mysql_query("TRUNCATE TABLE interlinks");

 mysql_query("INSERT INTO interlinks (title, url) VALUES ('$locstripped', '$loc')");

 }
} 
?>
```

TY

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ty guys, did it like this:

```
$urlstrip = basename($loc);
$linestrip = str_replace(array('-','_'), ' ', $urlstrip);
```

Answer (score 0):

You want only the last segment of the URL?

Try something like this.

```
$url = trim('http://www.site1.com/dir/this-is-page/', '/');
$url = explode('/', $url);
$url = array_pop($url);
$url = str_replace(array('-','_'), ' ', $url);
```

Comment: The last segmend "this-is-page" without the -

Comment: $locstripped = basename($loc); Maybe use this to get "this-is-page" But how do i get rid of the -?

Answer (score 0):

It's not very elegant... but it works.

replace

```
 $locstripped = $locstrip[4];
```

with

```
 $locstripped = $locstrip[count($loc) - 1];
 if(!$locstripped)
        $locstripped = $locstrip[count($loc) - 2];
$locstripped = str_replace('-', ' ', $locstripped);
```